# git - all files become modified after reinstall

Tags: git

Update:
thankfully, I recovery my .gitconfig, and it works.
(but I still want to know the correct way to solve this problem.)

Origin:
I reinstall my git (to use the new version of git)
however, it makes some files in my repository become modified
for example, before reinstalling, I have 3 files, A, B and C.
A has already committed.
B is modifying, but not yet add.
C is untracked.
after reinstalling, A and B become modified.
(however, only B should be modified, because I have committed A file.)
C is untracked (of course)

how should I solve this problem (making some modified files become not modified)?
BTW, there may has many A files and B files (**and I don't know whether the file is committed or modified**).

Answer (score 1):

to "unmodified" your files:

```
git checkout <file-path>
```

another 2 ways that I think could help you is to:
1.  "stash" your changes before reinstalling the git:

```
git stash
```

after reinstalling git do:

```
git stash pop
```

2. make a patch with all your changes and after reinstalling git just apply the patch.

Answer (score 1):

please check your settings concerning the handling of line-endings.

```
core.autocrlf 
core.safeclrf
```

maybe they have changed with new installation of git, so git tries to modify the line-endings of the files.